# Javascript: How to trigger an "onchange" event while the text element still has focus?

Tags: javascript

As far as I understand, the "onchange" event of a text input element is only fired when two conditions are true:

- The text has changed.
- The field no longer has focus.

So when you click off, it fires the event. How can I fire an event when the text has changed, but the field still has focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have access to the `keypress`, `keyup`, and `keydown` events; [the details](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) of when those fire can be found at Quirksmode.

Answer (score 2):

Reliably? You can't, yet.

You can catch the majority of changes by firing your update checker `onkeyup` as well as `onchange`. However whilst this picks up simple keyboard interactions, it fails to trigger on other events like cut-and-paste (there is `onpaste` in some browsers, but you can't rely on it), drag-and-drop, undo-redo and spellchecker changes.

HTML5 proposes `oninput` to solve this, but the implementation isn't there yet. If you really want to spot all input changes today you will have to `setInterval` a function that keeps checking the input's value to see if it has changed.